# Zend 2 Generate XML sitemap from console controller

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework2

I'm trying to generate the XML sitemap in a console controller action (so that it can be saved to a file rather than being generated on the fly).

The problem is that when running the scrip I get the error

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\Navigation\Page\Uri::setRequest() must be an instance of Zend\Http\Request, instance of Zend\Console\Request given
```

Is there a way to override this so that Zend thinks that it's being run from a http request?

My sitemap action looks like this...

```
public function sitemapAction()
{
    $this->log(Logger::WARN, "ConsoleController Was Run");

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if (!$request instanceof ConsoleRequest){
        throw new \RuntimeException('You can only use this action from a console!');
    }

    $event = $this->getEvent();
    $http = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('HttpRouter');
    $event->setRouter($http);

    $viewHelperManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager');

    $nav = $viewHelperManager->get('navigation');

    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTerminal(true);

    return $nav('sitemap')->sitemap();

}
```

Comment: 2 questions: is it console controller and why you are re building router? Maybe navigation doesn't compatible with console.

Comment: I wanted to make sure it had access to the http routes and not just the console routes. Yes it's a console controller.

Comment: There must be some way of generating a site map from a cronjob rather than generating it on the fly? for large sites it's impractical to do it on the fly